# Calculate the average score

Tags: c, average

Why my calculate the average score is wrong?

I have a function:

```
int student_average_scope() {
  char name[50];
  int group;
  int exam;
  int average = 0;
  int digit = 0;
  int counter_digits = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sscanf(student_list[i], "%d %[^0-9] %d", &group, name, &exam);

    while (exam > 0) {
      digit = exam % 10;
      average += digit;
      counter_digits++;
      exam = exam / 10;
    }

    printf("%.1f\n", (double)average / counter_digits);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where `student_list[i] = "4273 Константинопольский А. А. 4333 знзнз"` average is equal 3.9, but right answer 3.2! And if I make simple function, calculate the average score give me right output (3.2). Where I made mistake?

```
int student_average_scope() {
    int exam = "4333";

    int average = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int counter_digits = 0;

    while (exam > 0) {
        digit = exam % 10;
        average += digit;
        counter_digits++;
        exam = exam / 10;
    }

    printf ("%.1f\n", (double) average / counter_digits);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It Dosen't work" isn't a good explanation.Include more details like what is the output you are getting

Comment: @CoolGuy oh, sorry, thank you. I will modify my answer

Comment: first one gives me the right answer?

Comment: I get `3.3` when I did `13/4`(`average/counter_digits`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are failing to reset the variables back to zero when you move from one record to the next in your `for` loop. What you should do is this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    average = 0;
    counter_digits = 0;
    ...
```